# Unable to understand the following line of code : use of dist = 1.5*ATR(10); and inside for loop it is used as an array

Tags: algorithmic-trading, amibroker

Here dist is a variable but inside the for loop its used as an array in afl programming

dist = 1.5*ATR(10);

```
for(i = 0;i < BarCount; i++ )
       {
        if( Buy[i] ) PlotText( "Buy\n@" + C[ i ], i, L[ i ]-dist[i], colorGreen );
        if( Sell[i] ) PlotText( "Sell\n@" + C[ i ], i, H[ i ]+dist[i], colorRed,
        colorYellow );
        }
```

Comment: There's already a good write up about arrays on Amibrokers website [link](https://www.amibroker.com/guide/h_understandafl.html)

Answer (score 0):

ATR in amibroker to Calculates Average True Range indicator
[more about atr](http://www.amibroker.com/guide/afl/atr.html)

ATR function return an array.

```
dist = 1.5*ATR(10);
```

this line of code will return an array with each element multiply by 1.5